# Capturar JSON vacio y evitar error

Tags: ajax

Tengo un pedido AJAX, que se ejecuta al cargar la pagina de ticket, pero al entrar la primera vez no hay articulos en la sesion.
¿De que manera se evita o captura la excepcion **Requested JSON parse failed**?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   

listarDetalle();
});
function listarDetalle(){
 var accion="listar";
  
$.ajax({
 
        type: "POST",
        url: "//localhost/gestionweb/includes/php/procesoDetalle.php",
        data: { "accion":accion}, 
  dataType:"json",
  
        error: function(){
            alert("error petición ajax");
           
        },
        
        success: function(data){

         if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)){alert("sin articulos");}else{ 
         
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                       
                       var newRow =
                                        "<tr>" +
                                      
                                        "<td>" + item.id + "</td>" +
                                        "<td>" + item.cantidad + "</td>" +
                                        "<td>" + item.nombre + "</td>" +
                                        "<td>" + item.precio + "</td>" +  
                                        
                                        "<td>" + item.total + "</td>" +
                                        "<td><input type='radio' id='"+item.id+"' name='seleccionado' value='"+item.id+"'/></td>"+
                                        "</tr>";
                                subtotal=subtotal + item.total; 
                                 iva=(subtotal *0.21);     
                                 total=subtotal - iva;
                                    $(newRow).appendTo("#ticket tbody"); 
                              $("#sub").text(subtotal);
                              $("#IVA").text(iva);
                              $("#total").text(subtotal);
                            
                            
});

}}
```

Como veran lo intento pero no lo consigo..

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar

```
if ( json.length == 0 ) { //COMO SI CONTARAS LA LONGITUD DE CADENA
    console.log("SIN DATOS!")
}
```

Esta función puede resolver "undefined", también puede validarse por tal

```
if ( json.length == 0 || json.length == undefined ) {
```

O

```
if (!json[0]) alert("SIN DATOS!");
```

Este código te funcionara para cuando tu JSON sea un objeto

```
jQuery.isEmptyObject()
```

Mas info https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/

Saludos :)

Comment: En realidad es una factura, y recibe un array de objetos detalles, para mostrar el json uso:  $.each(data, function(i, item) y luego accedo a los campos dentro de data. Quizas por eso no me funciona el codigo de longitud y undefined

Comment: Osea si pongo console.log(data), no muestra nada, es decir ni entra al evento success, tendria que retornar un json vacio desde php